# MySQL Query Help Finding Rank by ID

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I'm trying to modify the following query to find the rank of a specific videoid and I'm not having much luck can anyone suggest a solution?

```
  SELECT videoid wins/loses as win_loss, 
         @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM cb_video, 
         (SELECT @curRank := 0) r  
ORDER BY wins/loses DESC
```

I tried doing a subquery like this but it fails:

```
SELECT rank 
  FROM (SELECT videoid wins/loses as win_loss, 
               @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
          FROM cb_video, 
               (SELECT @curRank := 0) r  
      ORDER BY wins/loses DESC) 
 WHERE videoid = 116
```

Also adding the videoid to the WHERE clause without a subquery just always shows the rank being the #1 position as it only returns one row:

```
  SELECT videoid wins/loses as win_loss, 
         @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
    FROM cb_video, 
         (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
   WHERE videoid = 116 
ORDER BY wins/loses DESC
```

Any ideas how to limit the result to a specific ID but still retain the rank? FYI I keep two columns (wins and loses) if that helps.

Comment: Your second approach seems right to me. What error did you get?

Comment: IME, the variable rank functionality can't be trusted if the table engine is MyISAM.  Numbers get skipped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.videoid, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cb_video b 
 WHERE a.videoid !=b.videoid 
 AND (b.wins/b.loses) > (a.wins/a.loses))+1 AS rank
FROM cb_video a
WHERE a.videoid = 116
```

Comment: a1ex07 that seems to work however I'm interested in your usage of the win loss ratio. Your query returns a ranking of 6 while Arek's query below returns a ranking of 8.

Comment: That's because my query returns the number of records where ratio is greater than current. For example, if we have 4 records were win/loss are 3,3,2,2 , my query returns rank = 3 for the last record , Arek's - 4. After running my query you will get two ranks 1, and 2 ranks =3

Comment: This will produce duplicate rank values when there's the same ratio -- it's like using the analytic `DENSE_RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: What is the right depends on what you are looking for... You second approach (fixed by Arek Jablonski) does not return rank, it returns row number.

Comment: @OMG Ponies : `DENSE_RANK` will look like `...COUNT(DISTINCT (b.loses/b.wins))...` and won't have gaps though.

Comment: Not gaps, just the rank will be repeated.  IE: If two records tie for second place, their rank value will both be "2".

Comment: Surely, but I believe for such cases tiebreaker[s] must be presented (or prize is split in case of ties).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT videoid, rank FROM (SELECT videoid, wins/loses as win_loss, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM cb_video, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r  ORDER BY wins/loses DESC) s WHERE videoid = 116
```

Comment: This works too. Yours returns a ranking of 8. I'm trying to figure out which on is more accurate yours or a1ex07s above.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on simple subset created of similar table as you've described...
It returns the ONE video and its actual final Rank of the entire set...

```
select *
   from ( SELECT 
              videoid, 
              wins, 
              losses, 
              wins/losses,       
              @curRank := @curRank +1 Rank
           FROM 
              cb_video,
              ( select @curRank := 0 ) r
           order by 
              wins/losses desc ) PreQuery
    where
       PreQuery.VideoID = 116
```

Comment: Change the table engine to MyISAM, and see if you still get the same results.  I wager you won't...